# CRON Job to ping running container port and restart server in case of error

Tags: docker, cron

I have a python script running inside a docker container, with a REST API inside the container (localhost access to port from 8085)

Things work great (http://{host_ip_address:8085}), but once in a while the container stops responding to http requests, restarting the container solves the issue.

I'd like to setup a CRON job, within the host running the container, to check that http://localhost:8085 is responding, and if not, restart the container.

it is ok for me to restart all running containers on the machine, so the failure command can be:

```
docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Typical container practice is that it should be safe to stop, delete, and recreate containers; though that depends on the application and it means knowing the `docker run` commands involved.  `docker restart` may not be safe since it doesn't reset the container filesystem to a known state, so there are common problems around pid files being left behind for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

docker has the `HEALTHCHECK` instruction to poll the container via any command we want. unfortunately, at the time of writing, the container will not restart automatically if unhealthy.

Here is my HEALTHCHECK instruction in Dockerfile (app is exposing port 8085):

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=30s --start-period=45s \
    CMD curl -f --retry 6 --max-time 5 --retry-delay 10 --retry-max-time 60 "http://localhost:8085" || bash -c 'kill -s 15 -1 && (sleep 10; kill -s 9 -1)'
```